# Performance regression after upgrading compatibility level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2017

We've recently migrated our database to a new server. The old server was using Windows Server 20008R2 and SQL Server 2008R2. The new server is using Windows Server 2019 and SQL Server 2017.

The migration run smoothly until we changed  the compatibility level (CL) of the database, from

- SQL Server 2008 (100)

to

- SQL Server 2017 (140).

You can see the difference in the execution plan of a stored procedure in the pictures below:

This is an excerpt of the plan for CL: SQL Server 2008 (100):

[image: Execution plan for CL SQL Server 2008]

and this an excerpt of the plan of the exact same query for CL: SQL Server 2017 (140):

[image: Execution plan for CL SQL Server 2017]

Somehow parallelism is lost when upgrading the CL. How can I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Upload your actual plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the links to your question. In addition to being serial, the 2017 has a sort operator not seen in the 2008 plan. You might try `ALTER DATABSE SCOPED CONFIGURATION...SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql) and with the db in the native 140 compatibility level.

Comment: Adding that it is generally not uncommon for queries in need to query/index tuning to perform worse after an upgrade.

Comment: The "troubleshooting " aspect is easy... It's the new cardinality estimator that was introduced wih SQL Server 2014. The hard part is actually fixing the problem. That can include rewriting queries so that they play nicer with the new estimator or betting to know the "Query Store" (introduced with SQL Server 2016)... But... That all takes time. A good "quick fix" is to force SQL Server to use the old CE for specific queries, like the one above, by using  **OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)**

Comment: @DanGuzman Unfortunately I cannot do this, because this would expose info about the schema of the database.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos is you use SentryOne Plan Explorer, there is an option to anonymize the plan and underlying schema.